# Copy full file path to clipboard as file object so the file can be pasted in a folder in windows explorer

Tags: vba, ms-access, winapi

I have file paths stored in a table and I want to be able to copy those strings to the clipboard so the user can right click in any folder and paste so the files are copied.

I'm using Access 2019 64 bit and have tried code from this forum but it crashes: https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/copy-a-file-from-a-specific-directory-and-make-available-in-clipboard.1111619/

The 64 bit version of that script make the app crash almost instantly, I don't have access 32 bit version to test that version.

This is the clean version of the code from that forum:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

' Required data structures
Private Type POINTAPI
    x As Long
    y As Long
End Type

Private Type DROPFILES
    pFiles As Long
    pt As POINTAPI
    fNC As Long
    fWide As Long
End Type

#If VBA7 And Win64 Then
    ' Clipboard Manager Functions
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function EmptyClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function CloseClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetClipboardData Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Long, ByVal hMem As LongPtr) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetClipboardData Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Long) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function IsClipboardFormatAvailable Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Long) As Long
    ' Other required Win32 APIs
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function DragQueryFile Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "DragQueryFileA" (ByVal hDrop As Long, ByVal UINT As Long, ByVal lpStr As String, ByVal ch As Long) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function DragQueryPoint Lib "shell32.dll" (ByVal hDrop As Long, lpPoint As POINTAPI) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalAlloc Lib "kernel32" (ByVal wFlags As Long, ByVal dwBytes As Long) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalFree Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As Long) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalLock Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As Long) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalUnlock Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As Long) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMem Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (Destination As Any, Source As Any, ByVal Length As Long)
#Else
    ' Clipboard Manager Functions
    Private Declare Function EmptyClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long
    Private Declare Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function CloseClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long
    Private Declare Function SetClipboardData Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Long, ByVal hMem As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function GetClipboardData Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function IsClipboardFormatAvailable Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Long) As Long
    ' Other required Win32 APIs
    Private Declare Function DragQueryFile Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "DragQueryFileA" (ByVal hDrop As Long, ByVal UINT As Long, ByVal lpStr As String, ByVal ch As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function DragQueryPoint Lib "shell32.dll" (ByVal hDrop As Long, lpPoint As POINTAPI) As Long
    Private Declare Function GlobalAlloc Lib "kernel32" (ByVal wFlags As Long, ByVal dwBytes As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function GlobalFree Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function GlobalLock Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function GlobalUnlock Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Sub CopyMem Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (Destination As Any, Source As Any, ByVal Length As Long)
#End If

' Predefined Clipboard Formats
Private Const CF_TEXT = 1
Private Const CF_BITMAP = 2
Private Const CF_METAFILEPICT = 3
Private Const CF_SYLK = 4
Private Const CF_DIF = 5
Private Const CF_TIFF = 6
Private Const CF_OEMTEXT = 7
Private Const CF_DIB = 8
Private Const CF_PALETTE = 9
Private Const CF_PENDATA = 10
Private Const CF_RIFF = 11
Private Const CF_WAVE = 12
Private Const CF_UNICODETEXT = 13
Private Const CF_ENHMETAFILE = 14
Private Const CF_HDROP = 15
Private Const CF_LOCALE = 16
Private Const CF_MAX = 17

' New shell-oriented clipboard formats
Private Const CFSTR_SHELLIDLIST As String = "Shell IDList Array"
Private Const CFSTR_SHELLIDLISTOFFSET As String = "Shell Object Offsets"
Private Const CFSTR_NETRESOURCES As String = "Net Resource"
Private Const CFSTR_FILEDESCRIPTOR As String = "FileGroupDescriptor"
Private Const CFSTR_FILECONTENTS As String = "FileContents"
Private Const CFSTR_FILENAME As String = "FileName"
Private Const CFSTR_PRINTERGROUP As String = "PrinterFriendlyName"
Private Const CFSTR_FILENAMEMAP As String = "FileNameMap"

' Global Memory Flags
Private Const GMEM_FIXED = &H0
Private Const GMEM_MOVEABLE = &H2
Private Const GMEM_NOCOMPACT = &H10
Private Const GMEM_NODISCARD = &H20
Private Const GMEM_ZEROINIT = &H40
Private Const GMEM_MODIFY = &H80
Private Const GMEM_DISCARDABLE = &H100
Private Const GMEM_NOT_BANKED = &H1000
Private Const GMEM_SHARE = &H2000
Private Const GMEM_DDESHARE = &H2000
Private Const GMEM_NOTIFY = &H4000
Private Const GMEM_LOWER = GMEM_NOT_BANKED
Private Const GMEM_VALID_FLAGS = &H7F72
Private Const GMEM_INVALID_HANDLE = &H8000
Private Const GHND = (GMEM_MOVEABLE Or GMEM_ZEROINIT)
Private Const GPTR = (GMEM_FIXED Or GMEM_ZEROINIT)

Public Function ClipboardCopyFiles(Files() As String) As Boolean

    Dim data As String
    Dim df As DROPFILES
    Dim hGlobal As Long
    Dim lpGlobal As Long
    Dim i As Long

    ' Open and clear existing crud off clipboard.
    If OpenClipboard(0&) Then
        Call EmptyClipboard

        ' Build double-null terminated list of files.
        For i = LBound(Files) To UBound(Files)
            data = data & Files(i) & vbNullChar
        Next
        data = data & vbNullChar

        ' Allocate and get pointer to global memory,
        ' then copy file list to it.
        hGlobal = GlobalAlloc(GHND, Len(df) + Len(data))
        If hGlobal Then
            lpGlobal = GlobalLock(hGlobal)

            ' Build DROPFILES structure in global memory.
            df.pFiles = Len(df)
            Call CopyMem(ByVal lpGlobal, df, Len(df))
            Call CopyMem(ByVal (lpGlobal + Len(df)), ByVal data, Len(data))
            Call GlobalUnlock(hGlobal)

            ' Copy data to clipboard, and return success.
            If SetClipboardData(CF_HDROP, hGlobal) Then
                ClipboardCopyFiles = True
            End If
        End If

        ' Clean up
        Call CloseClipboard
    End If

End Function

Public Function ClipboardPasteFiles(Files() As String) As Long

    Dim hDrop As Long
    Dim nFiles As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim desc As String
    Dim filename As String
    Dim pt As POINTAPI
    Const MAX_PATH As Long = 260

    ' Insure desired format is there, and open clipboard.
    If IsClipboardFormatAvailable(CF_HDROP) Then
        If OpenClipboard(0&) Then

            ' Get handle to Dropped Filelist data, and number of files.
            hDrop = GetClipboardData(CF_HDROP)
            nFiles = DragQueryFile(hDrop, -1&, "", 0)

            ' Allocate space for return and working variables.
            ReDim Files(0 To nFiles - 1) As String
            filename = Space(MAX_PATH)

            ' Retrieve each filename in Dropped Filelist.
            For i = 0 To nFiles - 1
                Call DragQueryFile(hDrop, i, filename, Len(filename))
                Files(i) = TrimNull(filename)
            Next

            ' Clean up
            Call CloseClipboard
        End If

        ' Assign return value equal to number of files dropped.
        ClipboardPasteFiles = nFiles
    End If

End Function

Private Function TrimNull(ByVal sTmp As String) As String
    '
    ' Truncate input sTmpg at first Null.
    ' If no Nulls, perform ordinary Trim.
    '
    Dim nNul As Long
    nNul = InStr(sTmp, vbNullChar)
    
    Select Case nNul
    Case Is > 1
        TrimNull = Left(sTmp, nNul - 1)
    Case 1
        TrimNull = ""
    Case 0
        TrimNull = Trim(sTmp)
    End Select

End Function

Sub Test()

    Dim afile(0) As String
    afile(0) = "C:\VSYS\test.txt"
    MsgBox ClipboardCopyFiles(afile)

End Sub
```

The problematic line is the call to copymemory api function.

```
            Call CopyMem(ByVal lpGlobal, df, Len(df))
            Call CopyMem(ByVal (lpGlobal + Len(df)), ByVal data, Len(data))
```

I have tried changing variables from long to longptr and enclosing parameters in the varptr function, but i don't really know what I'm doing because never used those api functions.

Changing this:

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMem Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (Destination As Any, Source As Any, ByVal Length As Long)
```

...to this:

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMem Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (Destination As Any, Source As Any, ByVal Length As LongPtr)
```

has no effect.

Comment: There are a ton of `Long`s there that should be `LongPtr`. If you make a mistake there, you'll only hit the crash on the `RtlMoveMemory` call since that accesses the memory, but likely you got an invalid address because of invalid calls before that. Don't add `PtrSafe` unless you're sure you've thoroughly checked which `Long`s should actually be a `LongPtr`

Comment: You are totally right. Thanky you @ErikA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still testing it but I think this version is working without any problem:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

' Required data structures
Private Type POINTAPI
    x As Long
    y As Long
End Type

Private Type DROPFILES
    pFiles As LongPtr
    pt As POINTAPI
    fNC As Long
    fWide As Long
End Type


' Clipboard Manager Functions
Private Declare PtrSafe Function EmptyClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function CloseClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetClipboardData Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Long, ByVal hMem As LongPtr) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetClipboardData Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Long) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function IsClipboardFormatAvailable Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Long) As LongPtr
' Other required Win32 APIs
Private Declare PtrSafe Function DragQueryFile Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "DragQueryFileA" (ByVal hDrop As LongPtr, ByVal UINT As Long, ByVal lpStr As String, ByVal ch As Long) As Long
'Private Declare PtrSafe Function DragQueryPoint Lib "shell32.dll" (ByVal hDrop As Long, lpPoint As POINTAPI) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalAlloc Lib "kernel32" (ByVal wFlags As Long, ByVal dwBytes As LongPtr) As LongPtr
'Private Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalFree Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As LongPtr) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalLock Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As LongPtr) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalUnlock Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As LongPtr) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMem Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (Destination As Any, Source As Any, ByVal Length As LongPtr)


' Predefined Clipboard Formats
Private Const CF_TEXT = 1
Private Const CF_BITMAP = 2
Private Const CF_METAFILEPICT = 3
Private Const CF_SYLK = 4
Private Const CF_DIF = 5
Private Const CF_TIFF = 6
Private Const CF_OEMTEXT = 7
Private Const CF_DIB = 8
Private Const CF_PALETTE = 9
Private Const CF_PENDATA = 10
Private Const CF_RIFF = 11
Private Const CF_WAVE = 12
Private Const CF_UNICODETEXT = 13
Private Const CF_ENHMETAFILE = 14
Private Const CF_HDROP = 15
Private Const CF_LOCALE = 16
Private Const CF_MAX = 17

' New shell-oriented clipboard formats
Private Const CFSTR_SHELLIDLIST As String = "Shell IDList Array"
Private Const CFSTR_SHELLIDLISTOFFSET As String = "Shell Object Offsets"
Private Const CFSTR_NETRESOURCES As String = "Net Resource"
Private Const CFSTR_FILEDESCRIPTOR As String = "FileGroupDescriptor"
Private Const CFSTR_FILECONTENTS As String = "FileContents"
Private Const CFSTR_FILENAME As String = "FileName"
Private Const CFSTR_PRINTERGROUP As String = "PrinterFriendlyName"
Private Const CFSTR_FILENAMEMAP As String = "FileNameMap"

' Global Memory Flags
Private Const GMEM_FIXED = &H0
Private Const GMEM_MOVEABLE = &H2
Private Const GMEM_NOCOMPACT = &H10
Private Const GMEM_NODISCARD = &H20
Private Const GMEM_ZEROINIT = &H40
Private Const GMEM_MODIFY = &H80
Private Const GMEM_DISCARDABLE = &H100
Private Const GMEM_NOT_BANKED = &H1000
Private Const GMEM_SHARE = &H2000
Private Const GMEM_DDESHARE = &H2000
Private Const GMEM_NOTIFY = &H4000
Private Const GMEM_LOWER = GMEM_NOT_BANKED
Private Const GMEM_VALID_FLAGS = &H7F72
Private Const GMEM_INVALID_HANDLE = &H8000
Private Const GHND = (GMEM_MOVEABLE Or GMEM_ZEROINIT)
Private Const GPTR = (GMEM_FIXED Or GMEM_ZEROINIT)

Public Function ClipboardCopyFiles(Files() As String) As Boolean

    Dim data As String
    Dim df As DROPFILES
    Dim hGlobal As LongPtr
    Dim lpGlobal As LongPtr
    Dim i As Long

    ' Open and clear existing crud off clipboard.
    If OpenClipboard(0&) Then
        Call EmptyClipboard

        ' Build double-null terminated list of files.
        For i = LBound(Files) To UBound(Files)
            data = data & Files(i) & vbNullChar
        Next
        data = data & vbNullChar

        ' Allocate and get pointer to global memory,
        ' then copy file list to it.
        hGlobal = GlobalAlloc(GHND, LenB(df) + LenB(data))
        If hGlobal Then
            lpGlobal = GlobalLock(hGlobal)

            ' Build DROPFILES structure in global memory.
            df.pFiles = LenB(df)
            Call CopyMem(ByVal lpGlobal, df, LenB(df))
            Call CopyMem(ByVal (lpGlobal + LenB(df)), ByVal data, LenB(data))
            Call GlobalUnlock(hGlobal)

            ' Copy data to clipboard, and return success.
            If SetClipboardData(CF_HDROP, hGlobal) Then
                ClipboardCopyFiles = True
            End If
        End If

        ' Clean up
        Call CloseClipboard
    End If

End Function

Public Function ClipboardPasteFiles(Files() As String) As Long

    Dim hDrop As LongPtr
    Dim nFiles As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim desc As String
    Dim filename As String
    Dim pt As POINTAPI
    Const MAX_PATH As Long = 260

    ' Insure desired format is there, and open clipboard.
    If IsClipboardFormatAvailable(CF_HDROP) Then
        If OpenClipboard(0&) Then

            ' Get handle to Dropped Filelist data, and number of files.
            hDrop = GetClipboardData(CF_HDROP)
            nFiles = DragQueryFile(hDrop, -1&, "", 0)

            ' Allocate space for return and working variables.
            ReDim Files(0 To nFiles - 1) As String
            filename = Space(MAX_PATH)

            ' Retrieve each filename in Dropped Filelist.
            For i = 0 To nFiles - 1
                Call DragQueryFile(hDrop, i, filename, Len(filename))
                Files(i) = TrimNull(filename)
            Next

            ' Clean up
            Call CloseClipboard
        End If

        ' Assign return value equal to number of files dropped.
        ClipboardPasteFiles = CLng(nFiles)
    End If

End Function

Private Function TrimNull(ByVal sTmp As String) As String
    '
    ' Truncate input sTmpg at first Null.
    ' If no Nulls, perform ordinary Trim.
    '
    Dim nNul As Long
    nNul = InStr(sTmp, vbNullChar)
    
    Select Case nNul
    Case Is > 1
        TrimNull = left(sTmp, nNul - 1)
    Case 1
        TrimNull = ""
    Case 0
        TrimNull = Trim(sTmp)
    End Select

End Function

Sub TestCopy()

    Dim afile(0) As String
    afile(0) = "C:\test.txt"
    MsgBox ClipboardCopyFiles(afile)

End Sub

Sub TestPaste()
    
    Dim afile() As String
    ClipboardPasteFiles afile
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(afile) To UBound(afile)
        Debug.Print afile(i)
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I used it with Excel VBA and it worked for me, thanks. Only the first line appears in red and I deleted that line.

Answer (score 0):

As Erik A pointed out it was a question of variable types.

I have changed all long to longptr in api declarations and in all variables used when calling them.

I have also removed the conditional declaration as I only use 64 bits version and commented out one api declaration that is not being used.

Result:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

' Required data structures
Private Type POINTAPI
    x As Long
    y As Long
End Type

Private Type DROPFILES
    pFiles As Long
    pt As POINTAPI
    fNC As Long
    fWide As Long
End Type


' Clipboard Manager Functions
Private Declare PtrSafe Function EmptyClipboard Lib "user32" () As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function CloseClipboard Lib "user32" () As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetClipboardData Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Long, ByVal hMem As LongPtr) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetClipboardData Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Long) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function IsClipboardFormatAvailable Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Long) As LongPtr
' Other required Win32 APIs
Private Declare PtrSafe Function DragQueryFile Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "DragQueryFileA" (ByVal hDrop As LongPtr, ByVal UINT As Long, ByVal lpStr As String, ByVal ch As Long) As Long
'Private Declare PtrSafe Function DragQueryPoint Lib "shell32.dll" (ByVal hDrop As Long, lpPoint As POINTAPI) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalAlloc Lib "kernel32" (ByVal wFlags As LongPtr, ByVal dwBytes As LongPtr) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalFree Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As LongPtr) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalLock Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As LongPtr) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalUnlock Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As LongPtr) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMem Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (Destination As Any, Source As Any, ByVal Length As LongPtr)


' Predefined Clipboard Formats
Private Const CF_TEXT = 1
Private Const CF_BITMAP = 2
Private Const CF_METAFILEPICT = 3
Private Const CF_SYLK = 4
Private Const CF_DIF = 5
Private Const CF_TIFF = 6
Private Const CF_OEMTEXT = 7
Private Const CF_DIB = 8
Private Const CF_PALETTE = 9
Private Const CF_PENDATA = 10
Private Const CF_RIFF = 11
Private Const CF_WAVE = 12
Private Const CF_UNICODETEXT = 13
Private Const CF_ENHMETAFILE = 14
Private Const CF_HDROP = 15
Private Const CF_LOCALE = 16
Private Const CF_MAX = 17

' New shell-oriented clipboard formats
Private Const CFSTR_SHELLIDLIST As String = "Shell IDList Array"
Private Const CFSTR_SHELLIDLISTOFFSET As String = "Shell Object Offsets"
Private Const CFSTR_NETRESOURCES As String = "Net Resource"
Private Const CFSTR_FILEDESCRIPTOR As String = "FileGroupDescriptor"
Private Const CFSTR_FILECONTENTS As String = "FileContents"
Private Const CFSTR_FILENAME As String = "FileName"
Private Const CFSTR_PRINTERGROUP As String = "PrinterFriendlyName"
Private Const CFSTR_FILENAMEMAP As String = "FileNameMap"

' Global Memory Flags
Private Const GMEM_FIXED = &H0
Private Const GMEM_MOVEABLE = &H2
Private Const GMEM_NOCOMPACT = &H10
Private Const GMEM_NODISCARD = &H20
Private Const GMEM_ZEROINIT = &H40
Private Const GMEM_MODIFY = &H80
Private Const GMEM_DISCARDABLE = &H100
Private Const GMEM_NOT_BANKED = &H1000
Private Const GMEM_SHARE = &H2000
Private Const GMEM_DDESHARE = &H2000
Private Const GMEM_NOTIFY = &H4000
Private Const GMEM_LOWER = GMEM_NOT_BANKED
Private Const GMEM_VALID_FLAGS = &H7F72
Private Const GMEM_INVALID_HANDLE = &H8000
Private Const GHND = (GMEM_MOVEABLE Or GMEM_ZEROINIT)
Private Const GPTR = (GMEM_FIXED Or GMEM_ZEROINIT)

Public Function ClipboardCopyFiles(Files() As String) As Boolean

    Dim data As String
    Dim df As DROPFILES
    Dim hGlobal As LongPtr
    Dim lpGlobal As LongPtr
    Dim i As Long

    ' Open and clear existing crud off clipboard.
    If OpenClipboard(0&) Then
        Call EmptyClipboard

        ' Build double-null terminated list of files.
        For i = LBound(Files) To UBound(Files)
            data = data & Files(i) & vbNullChar
        Next
        data = data & vbNullChar

        ' Allocate and get pointer to global memory,
        ' then copy file list to it.
        hGlobal = GlobalAlloc(GHND, Len(df) + Len(data))
        If hGlobal Then
            lpGlobal = GlobalLock(hGlobal)

            ' Build DROPFILES structure in global memory.
            df.pFiles = Len(df)
            Call CopyMem(ByVal lpGlobal, df, LenB(df))
            Call CopyMem(ByVal (lpGlobal + Len(df)), ByVal data, LenB(data))
            Call GlobalUnlock(hGlobal)

            ' Copy data to clipboard, and return success.
            If SetClipboardData(CF_HDROP, hGlobal) Then
                ClipboardCopyFiles = True
            End If
        End If

        ' Clean up
        Call CloseClipboard
    End If

End Function

Public Function ClipboardPasteFiles(Files() As String) As Long

    Dim hDrop As LongPtr
    Dim nFiles As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim desc As String
    Dim filename As String
    Dim pt As POINTAPI
    Const MAX_PATH As Long = 260

    ' Insure desired format is there, and open clipboard.
    If IsClipboardFormatAvailable(CF_HDROP) Then
        If OpenClipboard(0&) Then

            ' Get handle to Dropped Filelist data, and number of files.
            hDrop = GetClipboardData(CF_HDROP)
            nFiles = DragQueryFile(hDrop, -1&, "", 0)

            ' Allocate space for return and working variables.
            ReDim Files(0 To nFiles - 1) As String
            filename = Space(MAX_PATH)

            ' Retrieve each filename in Dropped Filelist.
            For i = 0 To nFiles - 1
                Call DragQueryFile(hDrop, i, filename, Len(filename))
                Files(i) = TrimNull(filename)
            Next

            ' Clean up
            Call CloseClipboard
        End If

        ' Assign return value equal to number of files dropped.
        ClipboardPasteFiles = CLng(nFiles)
    End If

End Function

Private Function TrimNull(ByVal sTmp As String) As String
    '
    ' Truncate input sTmpg at first Null.
    ' If no Nulls, perform ordinary Trim.
    '
    Dim nNul As Long
    nNul = InStr(sTmp, vbNullChar)
    
    Select Case nNul
    Case Is > 1
        TrimNull = Left(sTmp, nNul - 1)
    Case 1
        TrimNull = ""
    Case 0
        TrimNull = Trim(sTmp)
    End Select

End Function

Sub Test()

    Dim afile(0) As String
    afile(0) = "C:\VSYS\test.txt"
    MsgBox ClipboardCopyFiles(afile)

End Sub

Sub Test2()
    Dim afile() As String
    ClipboardPasteFiles afile
    Debug.Print afile(0)

End Sub
```

Comment: Oh no! You should change to `LongPtr` when it's a pointer, not always... For example, `EmptyClipboard` and `CloseClipboard` return a `BOOL`, which maps to a `Long` in VBA. You did leave `wFormat`  alone, which is good, but then `wFlags` is wrong again. While these may not immediately cause problems, it's still not good.

Comment: Ok I changed those and made more tests and there is something else wrong actually. The test in my previous code works but when I pass long file paths and several files to ClipboardCopyFiles() then Access becomes a bit unstable, causing strange behaviours. Also pasting copied files in explorer has no effect.

Comment: Ah, for one, `pFiles` should be a `LongPtr` as well. It's usual when you have incorrect declarations to get all sorts of strange behavior instead of just a crash or an error when using WinAPI